# Disable Safari plugin without (re)moving the file

Tags: safari, google-chrome, adobe-flash

I've been Flash-free in Safari (5.0.3, my primary browser) for a while now, using Chrome with its bundled Flash Player whenever I have to.

I'm also developing a little bit in Flash for school, and have ended up using the Flash Debug Player, since it's really convenient to use `trace` for debugging.

I tried just putting the Debug Player inside my `Google Chrome.app`, similar to how the existing Flash Player is located, but Chrome refused to detect this, so I had to put it in `/Library/Internet Plug-ins`, and now Safari detects it too.

Is there any way I can get Safari to ignore this plugin, or something that makes sure Chrome can find it, and not Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rename the Flash debug plugin, in order to be available to Chrome.

- Go to 'Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/10.0.../Internet Plug-ins'
- delete the 'Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin'
- put there your debug 'Flash Player.plugin'
- rename it to 'Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin'
- restart Chrome

Comment: I think I tried that once before, but I'll give it another try to be sure when I get home again

Comment: @perfectlynormal I tried that way to install a newer version of Flash into Chrome and it did worked! Let me know of you have any issues..

Comment: Looks like it worked :)
Must've done something wrong last time. Probably typoed something...

Comment: Won't this be automatically overwritten with a new release of Flash by Chrome's autoupdate?

Comment: @GhostLyrics of course it will...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use the [clicktoflash](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoflash/) extension (also available from [Safari Extensions Gallery](https://extensions.apple.com/))?

Comment: I know that's a possibility, but iirc, there are some sites that detect you have Flash support installed, and use Flash instead of HTML5 for video for examples, so would like to avoid that..